# How to write a react typescript library to serve multiple data structures?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, shared-libraries

I'm trying to combine different webapps into a monorepo now. I have several modules in my apps which uses charts. I'm trying to write a library to chart the data from different data structures. I try to code a "graph-builder" module where I want to pass the "view", the "raw data" and graph specification array and the module will plot all these charts for that view.

My problem: The data's structure in each case is different and I want the library to handle any kind of data structure, with typing.

In a specific app, I could do it by defining data as:

```
...
data: TDATA1[] | TDATA2[];
...
```

But writing them into the library like this and checking with `type of` would defeat the purpose.

The chart specs would be similar to this:

```
export const GRAPH_DATA: IAppGraphProps[] = [
  // view = general
  {
    view: "general",
    datatype: "dataset",
    algos: [""],
    splits: ["clips", "validated", "invalidated", "other"],
    type: "bar",
    xKey: "sp",
    yKeys: ["dur_total"],
    seriesNames: ["col.duration_total"],
    subTitle: "col.duration_total",
  },
...
```

And the extension can be like the following for a data:

```
export interface IDatasetGraphProps {
  // data: TCVTBOX_ANALYZER_DS_INFO_ROW[];  // <= This was before merging webapps in a specific app
  data: any[];            // <= This is what I need to solve
  gd: IAppGraphProps;
  title?: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  cnt: number;
  colors?: string[];
}
```

Here is the idea (dataset statistic visualization):
https://cv-dataset-analyzer.netlify.app/examine/en/12.0

What are my possibilities for typescript in a react library to serve multiple data types?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: did you try Generics in typescript?

Comment: No, I did not, until now I didn't use more advanced stuff like Generics, Declaration Merging, Mixins, and Namespaces. I was just reading about them before posting and could not figure out a way. [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content) really seems promising. If you think it is the answer, you can write an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use generics from typescript like this:

```
export interface IDatasetGraphProps<T> {
  data: T[];
  gd: IAppGraphProps;
  title?: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  cnt: number;
  colors?: string[];
}

export interface TDATA1 {
  id: number;
}

export interface TDATA2 {
  id: string;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                   Success                                  
*/
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

const data1: IDatasetGraphProps<TDATA1> = {
  data: [{ id: 1 }],
};

const data2: IDatasetGraphProps<TDATA2> = {
  data: [{ id: '1' }],
};

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                    Error                                   */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
const data3: IDatasetGraphProps<TDATA1> = {
  data: [{ id: '1' }], // <=====Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
};
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you Ali, exactly what I need and well explained.